# Node Js Transformation JSON by JSON key

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I want to filter the following JSON result. but I am unable to tranform.

```
const result = 
[
  {
    id: 'e7a51e2a-384c-41ea-960c-bcd00c797629',
    type: 'Interstitial (320x480)',
    country: 'ABC',
    enabled: true,
    rank: 1,
    link: '',
    }];
```

to

```
[{
  "Interstitial (320x480)" : {
  "enabled": true,
  "rank": 1,
}];
```

Here is my code

```
const result = 
[
 {
  id: 'e7a51e2a-384c-41ea-960c-bcd00c797629',
  type: 'Interstitial (320x480)',
  country: 'ABC',
  enabled: true,
  rank: 1,
  link: '',
 }];

const fields = ['type', 'rank', 'enabled'];
const tranform = Object.assign({}, ...fields
  .filter(key => !!result[key]).map(key => ({ [key]: result[key] })));
console.log(tranform);
```

above code, I want to extract the key that mentioned in fields array

and the desired result should be

```
[{
  "Interstitial (320x480)" : {
  "enabled": true,
  "rank": 1,
}];
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: `const fields = ['type', 'rank', 'enabled'];` `->` Is the first index the key for grouping the next ones within an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code snippet

```js
 const results = [{
      id: 'e7a51e2a-384c-41ea-960c-bcd00c797629',
      type: 'Interstitial (320x480)',
      country: 'ABC',
      enabled: true,
      rank: 1,
      link: '',
    }];

    const transformed = results.map(result =>
      ({ [result.type]: { enabled: result.enabled, rank: result.rank } }));

    console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `map` and computed-property-name to dynamically create a key using a variable.

This is assuming the first index from `fields` is the main key and the next indexes are values to be extracted.

```js
const result = [{
  id: 'e7a51e2a-384c-41ea-960c-bcd00c797629',
  type: 'Interstitial (320x480)',
  country: 'ABC',
  enabled: true,
  rank: 1,
  link: '',
}],
      fields = ['type', 'rank', 'enabled'],
      [key, ...others] = fields;
      
const mapped = result.map(o => ({[o[key]]: others.reduce((a, c) => Object.assign({}, a, {[c]: o[c]}), {})}));

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: the result is not hardcoded  I just explained in my code

Answer (score 0):

result is an array of objects, so just changing this line in your code works

```
14c14
<   .filter(key => !!result[key]).map(key => ({ [key]: result[key] })));
---
>   .filter(key => !!result[0][key]).map(key => ({ [key]: result[0][key] })));
```

However if the result contains more than one object in the array, make transform a function and map it over result.

```js
const result = [{
  id: 'e7a51e2a-384c-41ea-960c-bcd00c797629',
  type: 'Interstitial (320x480)',
  country: 'ABC',
  enabled: true,
  rank: 1,
  link: '',
}];

const fields = ['rank', 'enabled'];
const tranform = r => ({
  [r.type]: Object.assign({}, ...fields
    .filter(key => !!r[key]).map(key => ({
      [key]: r[key]
    })))
});
console.log(result.map(tranform));
```